# How can I refer to variable as global in python

Tags: python, global

I was define a global variables which I wanted to change / give an actual value in a function.

When I tried to run it, I had an error message that informing the global variable is undefined.

please support, thanks. this is my code:

```
script_name = 'R2M_delayer.py'
recipe_name = 'R2M_E2E_delayer_NR_Ver_5.1'


global images
global metrology_images
logged_date = str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[0]
NR_log = 'NR_' + logged_date + '.log'
images_output_dir_path = '/usr/local/insight/results/images/toolsDB/lauto_ptest_s' + str(datetime.datetime.now()).split()[0] + '/w3'
metro_images_dir_path = find_dir_path_delayer.get_delayer_images_dir_path()
metro_callback_dir_path = '/usr/local/disk2/unix_nt/R2M/RecipeRun'


def images_check():
    estimated_num_of_images = 6640  # Hard codded for Sanity wafer #3
    Actual_Images_List = os.listdir(images_output_dir_path)
    images = len(Actual_Images_List)

    if images >= estimated_num_of_images or images < 7000:
        return True, images
    print("\nImages quantity is not equal to the actual images in results folder.\n")
    return False

print('                 ' + str(images) + ' images were send.\n')
```

Comment: 1) The `global` goes *into* the function. 2) You're not calling `images_check` anywhere, so the value isn't going to be defined. 3) You're *returning* `images` anyway, which would be the preferred way to return the value instead of modifying global variables.

Answer (score 0):

Problem has solved. I defined my global variables as fields in class and I was revalued that values of the fields in the functions.

Answer (score 0):

The global keyword goes *inside* the function. That allows you to call that variable outside the function. If you declare the variable outside the function, you don't need it. By the way, you're returning images anyway. It is much better to return the value instead of modifying global variables, because it may return its reference instead. Global variables are not a good practice because it can """mess up""" with your allocated local memory for your program. I recommend using the garbage collector library `gc.collect()` to collect any data of a global variable you are not using or managing.

Answer (score 0):

1. Declare global variables inside function definition, otherwise the scope of variables in function is always local.
2. To avoid "variable is not defined" error you can initiate them in the main code with some default value, e.g., images = None.
3. Agree with previous answer, try to not use global variables.